# Django signal post_save not created return two times

Tags: django, django-signals

When I try to update the post in signal, this error happens:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def post_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):

  if created:
    print(instance.author, " Created")

  else:
    print(instance.author, " was just saved")
```

Output:

```
root was just saved

root was just saved
```

This is when I update the post. It's running two times. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about your case but instead of printing, you should create it.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance,  **kwargs):
    try:
        instance.profile.save()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: i was sorry its like i had two save methods in my views

Comment: every things are fine

Comment: Good to know. Keep it up.